# How to pass a private variant value into declaration when overide new functions

Tags: fortran, private

For instance, I have a definition of `type A` in `moduleA`:

```
 Module moduleA
   implicit none 
   type A
        private 
        integer::N
   contains 
        ... 
        procedure,pass::f=>f1
   endtype
   private::f1
   contains
   real function f1(self,x)
        real::x(self%n)
   end function
   ...
 end Module
```

Then I found I meet a trouble when I override function `f` in other modules since I can not get the value of `N`. Even though I can have a method to get that, it seems that something like `real :: x(self%get())` is impossible in the declaration. I want to keep the rule of "private" in OPP. So what choices can I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. At least in the way you describe. It would be better to see an example of the overriding to suggest other options.

The `private` attribute works differently in Fortran and therefore you should not directly use rules from other languages that use OOP where `private` means something different.

In Fortran `private` is about the local module, in C++ it is about the derived classes. This is very different and you cannot use the C++ (or Java, etc.) rules for `private` in Fortran when `private` in fact means something else.

---

To be clear, I assume you wanted this kind of overriding:

```
   real function f2(self,x)
        class(B) :: self
        real::x(self%get())
   end function
```

You than get these messages:

```
private.f90(15): error #8497: Illegal use of a procedure name in an expression, possibly a function call missing parenthesis.   [GET]
        real::x(self%get())
---------------------^
```

or

```
        real::x(self%get())
                1
Error: 'get' at (1) should be a FUNCTION
```

So the compilers will not accept a type-bound procedure in the declaration. They would accept an ordinary procedure.

---

This compiles in gfortran, but not in Intel Fortran. But `get()` must be public, which you might not want:

```
   real function f1(self,x)
        class(A) :: self
        real::x(get(self))
   end function

   real function f2(self,x)
        class(B) :: self
        real::x(get(self))
   end function
```

In ifort I get

```
error #8383: The dummy arguments of an overriding and overridden binding that correspond by position must have the same characteristics, except for the type of the passed object dummy arguments.
```

which is weird.

Comment: OK. But by the way, is that any other suggestion to do this? Is there any trick pass n into the function?

Comment: BTW, I suggest to normally wait with the acceptation of an answer a bit more. To see if others gave you better answer or - if you ask for a clarification - until you get some response to that.

Comment: Also, I may just be wrong and there is a better way and someone will show it.

Comment: Thanks. A public method is much better and in some sense acceptable.  But the inconsistency by using different compiler is somewhat not good.

Comment: References to type bound procedures are permitted in specification expressions, subject to a number of restrictions (e.g. they must be pure).  The rules, requirements and manner in which specification expressions can be used result in some complexity, so compiler (and language) bugs happen.